# internet explorer not recognizing jquery in script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This works in FF and in Chrome but the click has no action in IE.

This is the relevant javascript, which is called after the entry is created.

```
<script>
$(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").click (function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("confirm")) {
    }
    else {
        $("img").remove(".confirmAppointment");
        $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").removeClass("confirm");
        $(this).addClass("confirm");
        $(this).append("<img src=images/confirmAppointment.png class=confirmAppointment id=roommateAppointment>");
        var entry = this;
        $(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
            $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
            var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", entry).text();

            alert (location);
        });

    }
  });
</script>
```

relevent php/html...the jquery immedeatly follows this in script tags

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo
'<tbody class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment">
    <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["name"].
            '</td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentlocation">'
                    .$row["location"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentSublocation">'
                    .$row["subLocation"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime">'
                .$row["startTime"].
            '</span>    - 
            <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime">'
            .$row["endTime"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentDate">'
                .$row["date"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>';
}

echo '</table>
```

JQUERY WITH ALERTS

```
 $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").click (function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("confirm")) {
    }
    else {
        $("img").remove(".confirmAppointment");
        alert ("TEST1");
        $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").removeClass("confirm");
        alert ("TEST2");
        $(this).addClass("confirm");
        alert ("TEST3");
        $(this).append("<img src=\'images/confirmAppointment.png\' class=\'confirmAppointment\' id=\'roommateAppointment\'>");
        alert ("TEST4");
        var entry = this;
        alert ("TEST5");
        $(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
            $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
            var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", entry).text();

            alert (location);
        });

    }
   });
```

Comment: Markup? [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), perhaps? _Anything?_ Well, if you're not going to put in the effort, then neither will I.

Comment: Sorry, i did just learn about jsFiddle today, and i will try that now...and I PROMISE I have put in effort on this.

Comment: @ayman ie8 is the one i have, but I think its failing in ie7 too

Comment: Try changing the `<script>` tag to `<script type="text/javascript">`. IE sometimes causes issues without it. Also, I would suggest reducing the length of the class name.

Comment: @Virendra  not the case. I tried

Comment: @virendra Thanks for the suggestion, I just tried that as Adam suggested it as well, below, but I'm still getting the same thing

Comment: can you paste your source code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Just to be 100% certain the click handler isn't firing, add `alert("Hello")` as the first line in that click handler - right before `if ($(this).hasClass("confirm"))`

Comment: okay, hang on, let me post the html quickly

Comment: if you can post you HTML, CSS, Javascript code in jsfiddle that will help in debugging faster. Also you may just try replacing `$(this).append("<img src=images/confirmAppointment.png class=confirmAppointment id=roommateAppointment>");` with `$(this).append("<img src='images/confirmAppointment.png' class='confirmAppointment' id='roommateAppointment'>");`

Comment: @Adam yes, the alert fires when I add it in as the first line

Comment: @radleybobins - then the click handler is running - there's something about what's in the handler that ie doesn't like

Comment: @Virendra - add that as an answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: @virendra I can't use the quotes because it is contained in a php echo, and backtics were causing errors...also, I just learned about JSfiddle today, so I'm a little naive about how it works.  Would it help eventhough the code is working in some broswers?  When I put my code in and ran it, I got the result I expected.  I'm going to add the html to the top first then I'll try an get a jsfiddle file together

Comment: @radleybobins - the missing single quotes are almost certainly the answer.  Get that into your echo, and if you don't know how, post a new question -- there are tons of good php devs here who can help you out

Comment: you can escape the quotes and use like this `$(this).append("<img src=\'images/confirmAppointment.png\' class=\'confirmAppointment\' id=\'roommateAppointment\'>");`

Comment: @virendra still no luck with the escaping

Comment: I know this is not a problem but why do you have 'reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment' as class as well as id for tbody? Also, is there any error displayed in IE?

Comment: @virendra oops, sorry, i thought I removed all the id tags, it was just a hold over from an old version, i dont reference that id anywhere, and i have removed it in my files now...i know they aren't supposed to be named the same...also no errors sohiwn in ie

Comment: Well, it would be great if you can copy the generated code and put it in jsfiddle. That would be much easier to debug.

Comment: Okay, I have been palying around with this more, please look at the newly pasted code at the bottom of my post...I put 5 alerts, 1 between each step, and all 5 alerts worked...so why doesn't the picture show up?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't know what you mean by copy the generated code into jsfiddle...i put what I pasted above in, ran it, and got ' .$row["name"]. '  ' .$row["location"]. '  ' .$row["subLocation"]. '
' .$row["startTime"]. ' - ' .$row["endTime"]. '  ' .$row["date"]. ' ...is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I just realized  that you are trying to append an image to **tbody**. I think that would be an invalid html and hence not working in IE. You would have to append the image to a **td** and not tbody.

Comment: i see, I will try that right now

Comment: Yes! I am getting some action now in IE!  I'm glad I know about that Tbody limitation now!  If you want to post that as an answer, I can mark you correct.  Thanks so much for putting some real time into it!

Comment: That's great. Yes, IE is many time strict about how the code should be. If you have invalid HTML code, IE can give you unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to append an image to **tbody**. I think that would be an invalid html and hence not working in IE. You would have to append the image to a **td** and not tbody. Try the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").click (function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("confirm")) {
    }
    else {
        $("img").remove(".confirmAppointment");
        $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment").removeClass("confirm");
        $(this).addClass("confirm");
        $(this).find('.confirm_button').append("<img src=\'images/confirmAppointment.png\' class=\'confirmAppointment\' id=\'roommateAppointment\'>");
        var entry = this;
        $(".confirmAppointment").click (function() {
            $(".confirmAppointment").unbind("click");
            var location = $(".reserveAPickupAppointmentLocation", entry).text();

            alert (location);
        });

    }
  });
</script>

echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

echo
'<tbody class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentRoommateAppointment">
    <tr>
            <td>'
                .$row["name"].
            '</td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentlocation">'
                    .$row["location"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentSublocation">'
                    .$row["subLocation"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentStartTime">'
                .$row["startTime"].
            '</span>    - 
            <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentEndTime">'
            .$row["endTime"].
                '</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class = "reserveAPickupAppointmentDate">'
                .$row["date"].
                '</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
<tr><td class="confirm_button"></td></tr>
    </tbody>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

IE might be a bit pickier about script tags.  Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: doesn't seem to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had face this type of problem many times,
possible solutions,

->ViewSource

- check, if there are any wrong html syntax, in my case, I messed up
  with ending tags, eg check your  tag or other syntax check
- best is to check with html [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) , http://validator.w3.org/, you will get more idea.
- on above code, I guess you need to put those on `$(document).ready`

if you are not getting solve, let me have your viewsource,

Comment: That's a nice tool, thanks for the tip.  Doesn't work great with php, but definitely useful.